# How to add multiple css rules at once through Dev-Tools or Firebug

Tags: css, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I have 300 lines of CSS, consisting of many rules that I need to test on a page.

I would preferably like to paste the rules in one go at the bottom of the main.css that the page is using - or add a pseudo "extra-main.css" sheet to the page with my rules.

I currently don't have access to the source of the page so I have to work on the live page. Not perfect I know.

What would be the best way to do this? Firebug, DevTools (Chrome), something else...

Comment: On dev tools when you inspect something, you'll see in the top right of the element there is the original CSS source name. Click that and paste your CSS and just hit CTRL+S to see realtime changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Within the Chrome DevTools' *Elements* panel click the source of the element, paste in your CSS to test and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to see the updates. You can click any element on the page you want to test as long as the CSS source file effects it.

[image: Pasting multiple CSS rules in Chrome DevTools]

Comment: Correct. As to replace a SCSS file in the browser itself would be in an unrecognised format. You will need to compile the SCSS file and then use the outputted CSS in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 2):

In Firebug it is similar to the Chrome DevTools, I just found out.

1. Open Firebug
2. Select the CSS tab
3. Select the css file you would like to edit
4. Select Live edit

[image: How to add CSS sources in Firebug]

Comment: Additionally to the animated image, you should add some steps describing how to paste the CSS.